# How to remove particular data from file using php

Tags: php, regex, file, logic

Present data in file ---

```
Kortrijk]]||75,592||74,790||73,777VWVVLG
Hasselt]]||65,503||68,085||70,584VLIVLG
Sint-Niklaas]]||68,277||68,290||70,016VOVVLG
Ostend]]||69,039||67,279||69,115VWVVLG
|22Tournai]]||67,291||67,379||67,844WHTWAL
|23Genk]]||61,532||62,842||64,095VLIVLG
|24Seraing]]||62,832||60,557||61,237WLGWAL
```

This is the data set i have in my `wiki.txt` file, i need to remove all content after "]]||" from all lines.

//Require data after code implementation

```
Kortrijk
Hasselt
Sint-Niklaas
Ostend
|22Tournai
|23Genk
|24Seraing
```

This is the code i came across, but dont have any idea how to use it in my code, i followed `preg_replace`, regular expression etc but all going above my head..help me plz and plz let me know any tutorial link that i can follow for these kind of working`(specially regular expression for a novice`).

```
$file="wiki.txt";
file_put_contents($file,str_replace('find','replace',file_get_contents($file)));
```

Comment: You don't need regex here. Try this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$arr = file("wiki.txt"); //will give you contents as array
$newContent = "";
foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
    $newContent .=substr_replace($val, '', strpos($val, ']'))."\n";
}
//add changed content back to file
file_put_contents("wiki.txt", $newContent);

//result is:
Kortrijk
Hasselt
Sint-Niklaas
Ostend
|22Tournai
|23Genk
|24Seraing
```

Comment: no doubt the code works.....but this code is not going to change data in the file..as i have around 1000s data set in that file...so its also a cumbersome process to apply that ctrl+c/ctrl+v

Comment: that code was only to show how can we get required content, see added code in answer , this will replace your old content from file and add new content as you require... Hope that helps..!

Comment: ...thx a lot bro :)  just a suggestion plz...how could i improve my code writing ability ?

Comment: One of the best ways to improve your code is to read a lot of other people's code.  Get involved with a large PHP-driven community like [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) or [Symfony](http://symfony.com/), see what others write, try to contribute and take the advice you're given.

Comment: well, its practice & practice that improves skills, read docs, codes from others, etc to update yourself. I guess that's what needed. You can check this site for info:: http://www.wikihow.com/Improve-your-Skills-as-a-Programmer

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/]]\|\|.*$/m', '', $fnames);
```

Matches ']]||' literally, then all characters (.*) until the end of a line '$' and replaces them with ''.

Also:  Check out this [tutorial on RegExp](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than "change" the file, you probably want to open the file, read the contents, then write the parts you want to a new file.  If everything goes as planned, replace the old file with the new file. Much safer that way.

```
<?php

$lines = file("input.txt");

$output = "";

foreach ($lines as $line) {
  $output .= substr($line, 0, strpos($line, "]")) . "\n";
}

file_put_contents("output.txt", $output);
```

Lots of ways to solve this.